# Dealing with multiple languages in Ranorex?

Tags: ranorex

For my automated tests, everything works fine, except only when it is in English, and this script needs to be able to run for Spanish versions of the same application too. I am not even sure if this is possible, but is there some way of making Ranorex do some sort of translations or some sort?

Currently, validation doesn't work because obviously the text is in a different language, how can I get around this? If it is even possible.

Answer (score 3):

Usually, when testing an application which can be represented in different languages I would suggest using language independent properties in the RanorexPath (for example an automation id if available). 
There are similar questions discussed in the Ranorex forum.

- http://www.ranorex.com/forum/nls-testing-local-language-testing-t8438.html
- http://www.ranorex.com/forum/localized-t3725.html#p15532

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same issue, and in fact, the displayed message/title is sometimes part of what I want to check depending on the chosen language.

What I did:

- My different languages are handled through an xml file
- the detection of my UI elements may be based on title (but I prefer unique ID when possible, like user1982826 said), in such a
  case, I make that title a variable through XSpy.
- In a code collection, I created a method that will initialize those
  variables depending on the expected language (I'm using xdocument to
  parse my xml)
- Then, I call that method at the beginning of the recordings needing those variables (don't forget to bind them).

It's not perfect (I need to call that method multiple times for the moment), but ranorex support pointed me that using databinding from supported external source should do the trick. In my case, I should be able to trasnform my xml in a CSV file at the very beginning of my testsuit, and then use databinding on that file with the very same variables I created: [data-driven-testing](http://www.ranorex.com/support/user-guide-20/lesson-3-data-driven-testing.html)

Don't know if it's helping, it probably depends on how you handle the different languages of your application...

Comment: Ok I just tried and the CSV + data binding is working very well. An advice just in case: if possible, use similar names between your variables and your CSV columns (for example), so you can do the full data binding in 2 clicks with the auto-bind button.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can build your validations around different languages. Basically you'd just set a flag as a global parameter or a parameter that's held in the Program.cs-s Main method.

So if flag is set to "Spanish" it would do the spanish validations and if "English" the same would apply. You'd just have to capsulate the validations correctly in an if/else statements with userCode modules.